# Songs Memorization

Tags: voice, acoustic-guitar, memorization

How do I improve my song memory? I've realized that I'm poor in cramming songs. I only sing one or two lines in most of the songs and it hinders making fun as I play.

Comment: Is it the tune, or the words that evade you?

Comment: I'm poor majorly in words.

Answer (score 1):

Memorizing music is achieved through repetition: by listening to a recorded version of the piece and by playing and/or singing that piece over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You say it's the lyrics that hang you up.  Option 1: learn to scat, and then the words won't matter.  Option 2: memorize the lyrics by *writing them down*.  Each time you write them down, you'll have fewer gaps.  Also, try to picture a visual story to help you with the memorization.